# jquery ajax insert and fetch at the same time when submit then the fetch data will be post on url of window.open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on the submit of #user_form_cert the data will insert at the same time will fetch 
this is the code that i have used , the insert works fine but the fetch is still not working it says undefined on the window.open url

```
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form_cert', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var purpose = $('#purpose').val();
        var com_tax_cert = $('#com_tax_cert').val();
        var form_type = $('#form_type').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"../controller/insert.php",
                method:'POST',
                data:new FormData(this),
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,

                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#user_form_cert')[0].reset();
                    $('#certModal').modal('hide');
                    var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"../controller/fetch_single.php",
                        data:{user_id:user_id},
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(form_type == 'Barangay Indigency')
                                window.open('../forms/barangayindigency.php?' + 'id=' + user_id);
                            else if(form_type == 'Barangay Certificate')
                                window.open('../forms/barangayclearance.php?' + 'id=' + user_id);
                            else if(form_type =='Barangay Business Clearance')
                                window.open('../forms/barangaybclearance.php?' + 'id=' + user_id);
                        }
                    })


                }
            });
    });
```

this is my fetch_single.php code.. please help thanks.........................................................................................................................................

```
<?php
include('../db.php');
include('../lib/function.php');
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
    $output = array();
    $statement = $connection->prepare(
        "SELECT l_name, f_name, m_name, sex, birthdate, citizen, contact, email, house_num, street, purok, precinct, birthplace, length_stay, civ_status, image_name FROM rec_personal
        WHERE id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."'
        LIMIT 1"
    );
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output["l_name"] = $row["l_name"];
        $output["f_name"] = $row["f_name"];
        $output["m_name"] = $row["m_name"];
        $output["sex"] = $row["sex"];
        $output["birthdate"] = $row["birthdate"];
        $output["citizen"] = $row["citizen"];
        $output["contact"] = $row["contact"];
        $output["email"] = $row["email"];
        $output["house_num"] = $row["house_num"];
        $output["street"] = $row["street"];
        $output["purok"] = $row["purok"];
        $output["precinct"] = $row["precinct"];
        $output["birthplace"] = $row["birthplace"];
        $output["length_stay"] = $row["length_stay"];
        $output["civ_status"] = $row["civ_status"];
        if($row["image_name"] != '')
        {
            $output['user_image'] = '<img src="../upload/'.$row["image_name"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="'.$row["image_name"].'" />';
        }
        else
        {
            $output['user_image'] = '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="" />';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}

?>
```

Comment: you are fetching all results and then encoding them so when you would decode you will have an array so your url code will not work..use mysqli_insert_id() and this will give you the latest id and fetch only that row if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

use full path in  window.open instead of using relative path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({url:"../controller/fetch_single.php",
                    data:{user_id:user_id},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
//You are fetching data in the 'data' variable that you have get on success.
                      var result = JSON.parse(data);
//you will get your user detail in "result". you can access your records like "result.l_name" 
                    }
                })
```

try this to access your user.